# Downloading S3 file as attachment using knox/node.js passthrough

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, response-headers, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am trying to get downloading files from S3 via node/knox working. My javascript call is working and successfully downloads the file, but I want to download it as an attachment. I have tried setting the headers to `'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=myfile.zip'`, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my sample code:

```
var mimetype = mime.lookup(product.filename);           
var headers = {
    'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + product.filename,
    'Content-type': mimetype
};

var get = knox.getFile(product.filename, function(err, result){
    if(err) { return next(err); }   

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + product.filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

    result.pipe(res);           
});
```

I have also tried setting those headers on the knox call, but still won't download as attachment.

Comment: Try changing "Response-Content-disposition" to just "Content-disposition"?  AFAIK the former is not a real header.

Comment: sorry I was tired, I have tried the correct header.

Comment: Looks right to me.  What's happening instead, is it trying to display the bytes in the browser?

Comment: Yeah. If I `console.log` the result, it just shows the bytes. I am using angular, so if you think this is looks ok, I wonder if it is client code related?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the problem wasn't my server at all, as I was unaware that you cannot use xhr (i.e. $resource with Angular) to download files as attachments. The simplest way I have found to get around this so far, is to only use xhr to validate the download, returning a token to the user which can be used non-xhr to get the actual file.